# What is the meaning of p-value in survreg output?

Tags: r, survival

I am trying to understand the output from the survreg{survival} function when fitting a parametric model to two groups of data. I consulted the help documentation, but didn't find it very helpful.

I am interested in whether survival is significantly greater when factor=1. Is this indicated by the p value in the output? Is this the p value of a likelihood ratio test?

```
library(survival)
#Data set
d <- data.frame(
TTE=c(6,12,54,54,60,6,6,90,96,96,6,6,54,60,96,6,6,6,60,60,6,30,30,48,60,6,6,30,30,54,6,6,
      96,96,96,6,96,96,96,96,6,6,21,30,96,6,30,30,90,96,6,6,96,96,96,6,96,96,96,96),
cen=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,rep(1,17),0,0,0,1,
      0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0),
factor=rep(c(0,1), each=30))

attach(d)

#Kaplan Meier plots of both groups for illustration
plot(survfit(Surv(TTE, cen) ~ factor),col=c('red', 'blue'))
legend('topright',c('factor=0', 'factor=1'), col=c('red', 'blue'), lty=1)
```

[image]

```
#Fit survival data to parametric model
survreg(Surv(TTE, cen) ~ factor, dist='lognormal')

detach(d)
```

[image]

Comment: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3059453/

Comment: Seems to be the LRT for the model vs the null. `1 - pchisq(2* diff(yourmodel$loglik), 1)`. See `?summary.survreg`